# Foxx with GraphQL doesn't work

Tags: graphql, arangodb, foxx

I followed that instruction [ArangoDB Foxx example](https://www.arangodb.com/2017/10/auto-generate-graphql-arangodb/) (an example that is described as working by copy & paste) to learn how to use Foxx and GraphQL, but I have errors:

```
at Object. (C:\ProgramData\ArangoDB-apps\_db\_system\test2\APP\node_modules\graphql-aql-generator\node_modules\graphql-sync\lib\execution\index.js:7:16)
at require (C:\Program Files\ArangoDB3 3.3.1\/usr/share/arangodb3/js/common/bootstrap/modules.js:95:21)
at Function.Module._load (C:\Program Files\ArangoDB3 3.3.1\/usr/share/arangodb3/js/common/bootstrap/modules.js:484:16)
at Module.load (C:\Program Files\ArangoDB3 3.3.1\/usr/share/arangodb3/js/common/bootstrap/modules.js:539:36)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (C:\Program Files\ArangoDB3 3.3.1\/usr/share/arangodb3/js/common/bootstrap/modules.js:616:12)
at Module._compile (C:\Program Files\ArangoDB3 3.3.1\/usr/share/arangodb3/js/common/bootstrap/modules.js:598:8)
at Object. (C:\ProgramData\ArangoDB-apps\_db\_system\test2\APP\node_modules\graphql-aql-generator\node_modules\graphql-sync\lib\execution\execute.js:29:16)
at require (C:\Program Files\ArangoDB3 3.3.1\/usr/share/arangodb3/js/common/bootstrap/modules.js:95:21)
at Function.Module._load (C:\Program Files\ArangoDB3 3.3.1\/usr/share/arangodb3/js/common/bootstrap/modules.js:439:27)
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (C:\Program Files\ArangoDB3 3.3.1\/usr/share/arangodb3/js/common/bootstrap/modules.js:520:13)
File: iterall
at Object. (C:\ProgramData\ArangoDB-apps\_db\_system\test2\APP\node_modules\graphql-aql-generator\node_modules\graphql-sync\lib\index.js:6:17) via ArangoError: cannot locate module
at require (C:\Program Files\ArangoDB3 3.3.1\/usr/share/arangodb3/js/common/bootstrap/modules.js:95:21)
at Function.Module._load (C:\Program Files\ArangoDB3 3.3.1\/usr/share/arangodb3/js/common/bootstrap/modules.js:484:16)
at Module.load (C:\Program Files\ArangoDB3 3.3.1\/usr/share/arangodb3/js/common/bootstrap/modules.js:539:36)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (C:\Program Files\ArangoDB3 3.3.1\/usr/share/arangodb3/js/common/bootstrap/modules.js:616:12)
at Module._compile (C:\Program Files\ArangoDB3 3.3.1\/usr/share/arangodb3/js/common/bootstrap/modules.js:598:8)
at Object. (C:\ProgramData\ArangoDB-apps\_db\_system\test2\APP\node_modules\graphql-aql-generator\node_modules\graphql-sync\lib\execution\index.js:7:16)
at require (C:\Program Files\ArangoDB3 3.3.1\/usr/share/arangodb3/js/common/bootstrap/modules.js:95:21)
at Function.Module._load (C:\Program Files\ArangoDB3 3.3.1\/usr/share/arangodb3/js/common/bootstrap/modules.js:484:16)
```

What should I do to make it work correctly?

Comment: Could you further explain when these errors occur? I just ran the example by adding a new service, the collections and modifying main.js in the service path without any problems.

Comment: Please explain the exact steps how you triggered the error. Also make sure to test this with the latest version (currently 3.3.7).